# Angular 4 catch extern events

Tags: angular

If I have this event

```
API.onResourceStop.connect(function () {

});
```

How can I emit it on Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular uses RxJs library to send events. You need create an Observable of the the callback.

> Creates a new Observable, that will execute the specified function when an Observer subscribes to it.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create

```
   const API= { 
     onResourceStop: 
     { 
       connect(fn) {
         setTimeout(()=> fn('connect'), 5000);
       }
     }
  };

  let observable = Rx.Observable.create( observer => {
    API.onResourceStop.connect(arg=>{
       observer.next(arg);
       observer.complete();
    });
  });
  observable.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value),
    err => {},
    () => console.log('this is the end')
  );
```